# Combine firestore queries with rxjs (OR query)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, ionic4

I'm trying to combine two firestore queries in an Ionic/Angular project using RxJS. I found [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/performing-or-queries-in-firebase-cloud-firestore-for-javascript-with-rxjs-c361671b201e) from which explains the basic principle, however, the `.combineLatest` method has been deprecated and I can't figure out how to pipe the two queries into a map instead.

```
caOrCoCities$: Observable<City[]>;

...

const californiaRef = this.angularFirestore
    .collection("cities", ref => ref.where("state","==","CA"));
const coloradoRef = this.angularFirestore
    .collection("cities", ref => ref.where("state","==","CO"));
```

Not sure how to update this below...

```
this.caOrCoCities$ = Observable
    .combineLatest(californiaRef.valueChanges(),
                   coloradoRef.valueChanges())
    .switchMap(cities => {
        const [californiaCities, coloradoCities] = cities;
        const combined = californiaCities.concat(coloradoCities);
        return Observable.of(combined);
    });
```

Comment: What is the RxJS version you are using?

Comment: @Nikhil version 6.4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RxJS 6 had several changes in syntax. You can change your code as shown below.

```
import { combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';

this.caOrCoCities$ = combineLatest(californiaRef.valueChanges(), coloradoRef.valueChanges())
    .pipe(
       switchMap(cities => {
         const [californiaCities, coloradoCities] = cities;
         const combined = californiaCities.concat(coloradoCities);
         return of(combined);
       })
    );
```

Comment: The correct non-deprecated variant of `combineLatest` in RxJS 6 is the one that accepts arrays. `combineLatest([a$, b$])`

Comment: @martin - Looks like there are several [overloads](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest#overloads) for this operator which are equally correct. I see both the variants in use in [official docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest), [learn-rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html), and in this [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#dep-methods).

Comment: All these https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/combineLatest.ts#L71-L101 are deprecated

Comment: @martin - Thanks for the info. Looks like the docs aren't updated. I didn't see any mention of it anywhere.